# How to fix Platform Exception: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I can successfully get username from the code below but I get this annoying exception (PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1, null)). Here's is the code

```
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestoreRecord
     .collection('users')
     .document(userId)
     .get();
    return snapshot.data['username'];
```

I have tried doing `await _firestoreRecord.document('users/' + userId)` to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you get that error, I would not expect the query to succeed at all.  Is there something you're not showing here?

Comment: I just added code to make sure user was not coming in as null. That means the above code was being run with ```userId``` as null. The change somehow fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not checking if user from Firebase Auth was null. I have added this:

```
    widget.auth.isMyuser(_userId).then((val) {
       setState(() {
         if (val != null) {
           _isMyuser = val;
         } 
       });
     });
```